# Увеличить val и изменить placehlder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача:
после нажатия на кнопку, `value` инпута должно попасть в `p`, одновременно с этим `placeholder` инпута должен стать `value + 100`.

Например: ввели 1 200 - в `p` попало 1 200, в `placeholder` попало 1 300.

Перепробовал все, что знал. Просьба - вводите только числа и пробелы после тысячных, не стал лишний код закидывать.

http://jsfiddle.net/gez0ux6m/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Задача: после нажатия на кнопку, value инпута должно попасть в p, одновременно с этим placeholder инпута должен стать value + 100.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var betNum = $('.price')
  var betNumVal = betNum.val().replace(/\s/g, ''); // Удаляет пробелы
  $('.input').text(+betNumVal + ' p'); 

  betNumVal = +betNumVal + 100; // Добавляет 100
  betNum.val('') // Чистит инпут
  // Добавляет в инпут число с пробелами через каждые 3 цифры
  betNum.attr("placeholder", (betNumVal).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1 '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="12" class="price">
<button class="btn"> btn</button>
<p class="input"></p>
```

Comment: Вся проблема в пробеле, Ваш выдает NaN, если ввести 1 100

Comment: @РомаХр исправил.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает